# How to install Socket.IO>=0.7.8 with npm on Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, ubuntu-8.04

I searched for a long time, but haven't found the right answer yet.

I'm not the only one who has/had problems installing Socket.IO >0.7.7 but other solutions didn't work for me.

A possible problem could be an old version of GNU tar (version is 1.19) but I don´t know how to upgrade it or if it is possible at all.

An Update to a newer version of Ubuntu is not possible for me at this time.

If there is no way to update tar or something similar: Can I install Socket.IO without npm?

Here is the Output of "npm install socket.io":

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.8.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.8.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.0.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-client/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.0.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-client/1.0.0
npm ERR! error installing websocket-client@1.0.0
npm ERR! error installing socket.io-client@0.8.7

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/___xmlhttprequest.npm/package/package.json'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32.2-xxxx-grs-ipv6-32
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/admin/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /home/admin
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! path /home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/___xmlhttprequest.npm/package/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/___xmlhttprequest.npm/package/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/___xmlhttprequest.npm/package/package.json'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/home/admin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:204:26)
npm ERR! error rolling back socket.io-client@0.8.7 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/___uglify-js.npm/package'
npm ERR! error installing socket.io@0.8.7

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/websocket-client/package.json'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32.2-xxxx-grs-ipv6-32
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/admin/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /home/admin
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! path /home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/websocket-client/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/admin/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/websocket-client/package.json'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/admin/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: After three days searching I finaly found a solution:

`npm install git://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io.git`

But I have no idea why that works.

Comment: Glad it worked for you but its not doing it for me. Edit: My error was a little different though, fixed it with sudo apt-get install make

Comment: You should really consider updating because extended server support is almost finished => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_timeline